# Observations used to derive orbital and timing information required for GPS satellites

Tags: gps

Although I have studied GPS receiver position finding procedure in some detail, I am struggling to find enough information to allow me to deduce how the essential highly accurate orbital and time information required for each GPS satellite is actually obtained. I can only surmise that the information is somehow slowly and iteratively derived, for each satellite, from all the satellite signals received (probably receiver time-tagged) by the earthbound GPS monitoring stations, that the position information is resolved in an earth-centred inertial frame-of-reference (ECIF) and that the time information (in the ECIF) is synchronized to that from the US Navy master time clock value referred to the earth's geoid. I realise that relativistic corrections are also required at the receiver for orbit ellipticity and to refer the satellite positions to the earth-centred, earth-fixed (ECEF) WGS84 frame of reference. I am particularly wondering whether any other types of observations of the GPS satellites are also involved and I'm hoping someone could kindly give me a rigorous-descriptive rather than mathematical explanation.